# pyTelegramBotAPI(telebot) как реализовать счетчик

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Я новичок, хочу написать простого бота для записи в очередь. Как правильно использовать переменные. Помогите пожалуйста со счетчиком

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def hendle_start(message):
   user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
   user_markup.row('клиенты в ожидании', 'записаться в очередь')
   bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "привет", reply_markup=user_markup)

a = 0

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def hadle_text(message):
  if message.text == "записаться в очередь":
     # a = a + 1
     bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "вы записаны в очередь, ваша очередь №{!a}".format(a))



bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую создать список из тех кто в очереди, добавлять их туда и получать индекс, что и будет их местом в очереди.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def hendle_start(message):
   user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
   user_markup.row('клиенты в ожидании', 'записаться в очередь')
   bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "привет", reply_markup=user_markup)

members = []

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def hadle_text(message):
  if message.text == "записаться в очередь":
    if message.from_user.id in members
      return bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Вы уже были добавлены в очередь. Ваш номер: {members.index(message.from_user.id) + 1}"
    members.append(message.from_user.id) #Сюда введите то через что вы идентифицируете пользователя user_id я ввел для примера.
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "вы записаны в очередь, ваша очередь №{}".format(members.index(message.from_user.id) + 1))



bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: А что будет если юзер опять захочет в очередь?

Comment: @PavelDurmanov отредактировал

Comment: `if members.get(message.from_user.id, None):` -> `if message.from_user.id in members`